# Eclipse: Jump to current execution point

Tags: eclipse

In IntelliJ Idea there is a [shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/finding-the-current-execution-point.html) for jumping to current execution point, when program is suspended. Is there a way to do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always suspend the main thread in Eclipse debug perspective.

Once you suspend the thread, current stack of execution will be shown. Just click over it and you are taken to the class and line where it is stopped.

Also the class source code has to be in the class path for the source code navigation.

Please check here for more details.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suspending_threads.htm

Best Regards,

Saurav